# How to differentiate between picking and typing a date input value?

Tags: javascript, html, svelte

If a user picks a date, it should be sent to the server immediately. If they type the date, it should be sent on blur. Unfortunately, the oninput event is triggered for each keydown event as well. How can one distinguish this effectively to avoid unnecessary server requests while typing?

svelte

```
       <input
        value={from}
        type="date"
        on:input={onInputfrom} // also so gets triggered while typing
        on:blur={onBlurFrom}
      />
```

Comment: There is not much to distinguish the difference. You can add a delay before sending and cancel if another action happens. You can play around with key events.

Comment: Debouncing is a really good idea @epascarello. vuvu - You've said you want to wait until blur, but the real goal is not to spam the server, right? If so, debouncing would do that.

Comment: Thirded. I think you really do want just a debounce on the server event instead of trying to guess what the user is doing input-wise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd want to do extensive testing to validate it, but you could assume that the `input` event you get immediately after a `keydown` event is becasue the user is typing rather than picking from the popup calendar. For instance, you might assume any `input` within 10ms of a `keydown` is from typing, and any other is from picking. (Pasting would trigger it as well.)

I haven't tried Svelte yet, but here's a sketch of it using the DOM API:

```js
const input = document.querySelector("input[type=date]");

let keydown = false;
input.addEventListener("keydown", () => {
    keydown = true;
    setTimeout(() => {
        keydown = false;
    }, 10);
});
input.addEventListener("input", () => {
    if (!keydown) {
        console.log("picked");
    } else {
        console.log("typed");
    }
});
```

```html
<input type="date">
```